# Error in mean and mode in R

Tags: r, mean

I have the following data. I want to get mean from each column, which is mode for nominal data.

```
df1<-data.frame(c("a","a"),c("b","d"),c(1,5),c(4,8))
names(df1)<-c("x","y","z","w")
df1
  x y z w
1 a b 1 4
2 a d 5 8
df2<-as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=4,nrow=1))
names(df2)<-c("x","y","z","w")
df2$x<-names(table(df1$x))[table(df1$x)==max(table(df1$x))]
df2$y<-names(table(df1$y))[table(df1$y)==max(table(df1$y))]
df2$z<-mean(df1$z)
df2$w<-mean(df1$w)
```

If the data frame only contains a data, and one of the nominal columns of the next data is different with the previous one, then the following error is showing.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, y, value = c("b", "d")) :
replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

What can I do to fix this error?Thank you so much for your help

Comment: When I run the above function on the main data, when I want to put the result of this averaging instead of the previous data (I want to update), instead of the nominal data it puts the number 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to calculate either the mean or mode of each column:

```
get.mean.mod <- function (df) {
data.frame(lapply(df, function (x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) return (mean(x))
    freq <- table(x)
    names(freq)[which.max(freq)]
  }))
}
get.mean.mod(df1)

#   x y z w
# 1 a b 3 6
```